# SQL Server : how to calculate the balance correctly WITH ExpireTime?

Tags: sql, sql-server, function

It is necessary to calculate the balance of bonuses on some date, taking into account the lifetime of bonuses for each transaction. `LifeTime` term is in the `ExpireTime` column. Type 10 - plus transaction, Type 20 - minus transaction. When `ExpireTime` comes, bonuses should expire.

| Type | TransactionTime | BonusSum | ExpireTime |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 2021-03-22 15:27:03.270 | 4608,00 | 2022-03-22 15:27:03.270 |
| 10 | 2021-03-22 15:41:04.553 | 4608,00 | 2022-03-22 15:41:04.553 |
| 20 | 2021-03-24 18:20:12.423 | -3,50 | 2099-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 10 | 2021-03-24 18:20:12.423 | 2508,00 | 2022-03-24 18:20:12.423 |
| 10 | 2021-03-24 18:20:12.423 | 1000,00 | 2021-04-03 18:20:12.423 |
| 10 | 2021-03-24 18:20:12.423 | 1200,00 | 2021-04-02 18:20:12.423 |
| 10 | 2021-03-24 18:20:12.423 | 1380,00 | 2021-03-31 18:20:12.423 |
| 20 | 2021-03-25 09:20:12.423 | -2200,00 | 2099-03-24 18:20:12.423 |
| 20 | 2021-03-25 10:07:26.123 | -3,50 | 2099-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 10 | 2021-03-25 10:07:26.140 | 2508,00 | 2022-03-25 10:07:26.140 |
| 10 | 2021-03-25 10:07:26.140 | 1000,00 | 2021-04-04 10:07:26.140 |
| 10 | 2021-03-25 10:07:26.140 | 1200,00 | 2021-04-03 10:07:26.140 |
| 10 | 2021-03-25 10:07:26.140 | 1380,00 | 2021-04-01 10:07:26.140 |

My first idea was:

```
declare @BalanceDate datetime  = getdate()

select sum(BonusSum)
from BonusTransaction
where ExpireTime > @BalanceDate
```

But this is not true because it does not take into account that bonuses could have been credited and debited before the balance was received.

Then I tried something like this:

```
select 
    sum (case when (ExpireTime > @BalanceDate and [Checkx] = 10) then BonusSum end) - 
    sum(case when  Checkx = 20 then BonusSum  end) -
    sum(case when (ExpireTime < @BalanceDate and [Checkx] = 10) then BonusSum  end)
from 
    BonusTransaction
```

But that's not true either. Also I tried using window functions something like this:

```
select max(Sum) as Balance 
from
    (select sum(BonusSum) over (order by [TimeInsert] rows between unbounded preceding and current row) as Sum
     from BonusTransaction) t
```

Help please, I'm completely confused.

Comment: Desired results and a *clear* explanation would help.

Comment: You talk about that the bonus could have been credited or debited; how do *you* know that? There no credited or debited column in your data. What happens when a bonus has been credited or debited?

Comment: I apologize for the incomplete explanation if it was such. 
Type 10 - is a credit transaction (-2200, -3.5,-3.5 im my exemple), Type 20 - is a debit transaction (all other). 
I need to find out the balance for the current date, taking into account ExpireTime.

Comment: Correct balance will be: 
4608,00 + 4608,00  - 3,50 + 2508,00 + **1000,00 + 1200,00 - 2200,00** - 3,50 + 2508,00 = 14225
These transactions are not counted because they were not in time credited before ExpireTime:
|1380,00 |2021-03-31 18:20:12.423|     
|1000,00 |2021-04-04 10:07:26.140|     
|1200,00 |2021-04-03 10:07:26.140|     
|1380,00 |2021-04-01 10:07:26.140|